# How to prevent sharing user defined session in multiple tabs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to login as different users in different tabs of same browser.And I want to store user id,taken from database in Session["id"] on each login.How to prevent sharing of session["id] in multiple tabs?

Answer (score 4):

Generally browsers share session state between multiple tabs by default.You may try this code to avoid the sharing ie, try to have tab based browser – session handling:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You may also check [how to prevent the two session on a single browser using asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1665430.aspx)

Comment: But how can I create my own session variables using this?

Comment: How to use session variables if  we apply this code? @Midhuna  how did you mange to use session variables?